# DATATABLE plugin Fetch only first row only in dynamic data

Tags: php, search, datatable, fetch, row

```
<div class="table-responsive">
    <table class="table table-hover" id="dataTable" width="100%" cellspacing="0" >
        <thead>
            <tr class=" card-header py-2" style=" text-align:center;">
                <th> Er no</th>
                <th> Name</th>
                <th> Branch</th>
                <th> Adm Year</th>
                <th>Profile</th>
            </tr>
            <?php
            if (isset($_POST['pass'])) {
                $d = $_POST['spass'];
                include('bcpdb.php');
                $iq = "select * from stuinfo where ERNO  like '%$d' ";
                $qs = mysqli_query($con, $iq);
                //echo "Serch Query Data";
                if (!$qs) {
                    echo mysqli_error($con) . " DATA NOT INSERTED";
                }
            } else {
                include('bcpdb.php');
                $iq = "select * from stuinfo ";
                $qs = mysqli_query($con, $iq);
                //echo "select Query Data";
            }
                                   
            if (!$qs) {
                echo mysqli_error($con) . " DATA NOT INSERTED";
            }

            while ($res = mysqli_fetch_assoc($qs)) {
            ?>

        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td> <?php echo $res['ERNO']; ?></td>
                <td> <?php echo $res['SNAME']; ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $res['BRANCH']; ?></td>
                <td> <?php echo $res['ADMYEAR']; ?></td>
                <td style="text-align:center;">
                    <a href="profile.php?erpass= <?php echo $res['ERNO'] ?> " class=" fas fa-address-card fa-1x "></a>
                </td>
                <?php
                }
                ?>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
```

Just show rows in page  not fetch all rows in datatable. I want all of the data of database fetch in datatable plugin, when I put some data in html table row column then it works perfectly, fetch and search all rows of data but in database data which fetch by select query, fetch only one row

```
  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/44FRd.jpg
```

Comment: Are you sure you really want to create a new `tbody` element for each single row of data …?

Comment: thank you bro , i remove tbody ,now all ok...